# Expo start shows "Starting Metro Bundler on port" forever

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on react native project.

It worked well before I reinstall computer OS.
Now if I run expo start it just show this.

```
Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
```

This takes forever.
If I run android emulator here, then this error appears.

```
Couldn't start project on Android: could not install *smartsocket* listener: 
    cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address 
    (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

What's wrong here? I am using Genymotion simulator.

Comment: Can you share more information please? like what commands did you run etc?

Comment: I just ran "expo start".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.

I just set path environment to genymotion adb tool directory.

```
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools
```

And now it works well.

Thanks.